# VfW : Changing video resolution

Tags: c#, winapi, video, video-capture, vfw

I'm trying to change video capture resolution in VfW (Video for Windows), but I couldn't find any useful structure or method. It seems the only way to change video setting is using `CAPTUREPARMS` structure. But It doesn't have any field to set video capture resolution.

Any advice will be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution is changed through Format Dialog associated with capture device. You are supposed to pop up format dialog with `WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT` then user might change the resolution interactively using choices provided by the driver, then you obtain new settings via [`CAPSTATUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756939.aspx) structure.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I don't want to use embedded capture device dialog, is there another way to set resolution ?

Comment: Once user applied settings through dialog, I think you can obtain format via `WM_CAP_GET_VIDEOFORMAT` and then later set it back `WM_CAP_SET_VIDEOFORMAT` without user interaction.